# how to fix npm install failed in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am trying to dockerize my small reactjs app.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm install // gives the error when executing this step
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "cyberhr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "3d-force-graph": "^1.60.11",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.7.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-tsne": "^0.2.0",
    "d3-dsv": "^1.2.0",
    "mdbreact": "4.25.3",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-force-graph": "^1.32.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "tsne-js": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "renamer": "^1.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

But it fails at the `npm install` step and gives the following error

> Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 244

Here is a screenshot of the error in detail

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I had this challenge a while back. Make sure Node is properly installed. I solved mine by running `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm` in the root of my application. You could try that too.

Comment: This is a `Dockerfile`. I am using the latest `node` image. I will check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Can you replace the image with the actual text of the error message?  The error you quote is just a "it didn't work" error.  It'd also be helpful to know whether you can install the same package in a clean host Node environment.

Comment: Did you  ever figure out how to resolve this? I am getting this issue to no avail.

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also had to copy `package-lock.json` to the `Dockerfile` and it worked. I only had to do this though when running `npm install` gave me vulnerabilities.

Try:

```
COPY package.json package-lock.json .
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
RUN npm i --force
```